# Beowulf Cluster For MD simulations

Tags: molecular-dynamics, hpc

What would you recommend as an all-in-one cluster management software for a Beowulf cluster? We have about 7(most of them are 8 core machines and 1 is a 48 core machine) very good compute nodes in our research group and they are currently managed using Rocks and run Centos 6. We have been doing MPI-based computations, particularly, molecular simulations (Molecular Dynamics and Monte Carlo Simulations) reliably but we would now like to update the software. I suppose doing a system upgrade would break packages and reinstalling the cluster is a better option. I am wondering if we should use Rocks again or go for some other all-in-one solutions. We would want something that's easy to maintain (we all have experience with linux but not server management) and has LTS.

So, my questions are: 1. Is there a Debian-based option like PelicanHPC that is good for deploying on a long term basis? 2. Is building a beowulf cluster based on Debian/Ubuntu/Centos 7 from scratch a good idea?